# Having trouble comparing lists and lists of list

Tags: python

I have a list of ints and a list of lists. I need to compare the two.

The list of lists has a name, and a set of ints. My list just has a set of ints.

I know that in python you can just say `is list == list`. However, the order the ints are in is import and in my list of lists I also have a name before the ints.

Example my list will be `4 1 6` while a list I need to compare it to will be `bob 6 7 2`. I just need to compare the ints and if i compare `4 1 6` to `1 6 4` or `1 4 6` it would not compare.

I've tried using loops but am not getting the result I want.

`chdnalist` will be one list just a set of 3 ints. `dnalist` is a list of lists and one list will be `bob, 4, 1, 3` the next will be `alice 9, 6, 4`.

I need to compare the three ints from `chdnalist` to the three ints in `dna` list and print the name if it matches including order.

Here is the set of loops I was trying. Currently the s loop doesn't increment.

```
def compare(dnalist, chdnalist):
    for i in range(1, len(dnalist)):
        for s in range(1, len(dnalist[1])):
            print (s)
            if (chdnalist[i - 1] != dnalist[i][s]):
                break
            if (s == len(dnalist[1])):
                print (dnalist[i][0])
                return
            else:
                print ("No Match")
    return
```

This is a copy of the csv file that becomes my list of lists (dnalist).

```
name,AGATC,AATG,TATC
Alice,2,8,3
Bob,4,1,5
Charlie,3,2,5
```

I happen to know that the text file I use to create the list I compare it to when it has been translated turns into `4,1,5` (chdnalist).  However, when I go to compare them the s loop doesn't iterate.  It only runs once.

Comment: I'm a little confused -- do you want order to matter or not when comparing?

Comment: i'm confused as well, but if you want to drop the first entry out of `l = ['Alice',2,8,3]` you can slice the list with `l[1:]`

Comment: I think using `pandas` is better for you

Comment: Yes order does matter.

Answer (score 5):

Use spread assignment to split the name from the ints when iterating over `dnalist`. Then you can use `==` to compare the list of ints.

Also, `No match` should only be printed at the end of the loop, not during each iteration, since there could be a later match.

Since you read `dnalist` from a CSV file, everything will be read as strings, not integers. You'll need to convert them to integers before comparing.

```
def compare(dnalist, chdnalist):
    for name, *dna in dnalist:
        dna = list(map(int, dna))
        if dna == chdnalist:
            print(name)
            return
    print("No match")
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/51QyVd)

Comment: Barmer, thank you for the help.  However, I just inputted you code and ran it.  I still get no match.   I had the program print chdnalist and it printed 4,1,5 so I know that it is correct.

Comment: When you read from the CSV file, did you convert the numbers to `int`? If not, they're still strings.

Comment: I've added a demo showing it works if `dnalist` actually contains ints.

Comment: That is possible.  I have not been programming with python long.  I've got some guesses as to how to do that but being a list of lists I'm not 100% sure.  Would I have to copy them out of the list and convert them then compare?  Or is there an easier way?

Comment: I've added it to the function.

Comment: Thank you!  But I have one more question.  I'm getting a value error.  I think it's trying to convert the first line with "AGATC", "AATG", and "TATC".  Can I use next(name)? or something similar?